# Let $\phi:G \rightarrow G'$. If $G$ have 8 elements. Can the image of $\phi$ have 6 elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi:G \rightarrow G'$. If $G$ have 8 elements. Can the image of $\phi$ have 6 elements?

It's the same as saying $\mathbb{Z}_8 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_6$??. Can you give me a clue ?? I feel lost.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I suppose $\phi$ is more than just a map ?

Comment: Do you know the (group) isomorphism theorems?

Comment: If $\phi$ is just any map from $G$ to $G'$ which does not attempt to force any restrictions on special properties, and $G'$ has at least $6$ elements, then of course the image can have six elements.  **However** when you impose the additional restriction that $\phi$ must be a homomorphism, i.e. that $\phi(a*b)=\phi(a)*'\phi(b)$, then there is a great deal more you can say about the image of $\phi$.

Comment: I try to apply "First Isomorphism Theorem". Let $\phi :G \rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism, then $G/ ker \phi \simeq Im \phi$... The order of $G$ its the same that the number of elements in it?

Comment: @Salvattore: You could edit your above comment into the question for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a homomorphism $\phi$, we have $\phi(G)\simeq G/\ker\phi$. With $|G|$ finite, this implies that $|\phi(G)|$ must divide $|G|$.

$6$ does not divide $8$, so there is no epimorphism $\mathbb{Z}_8\mapsto\mathbb{Z}_6$. But there is a homomorphism that uses only $2$ elements of $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: If order of the image of $ \phi $ divide order of $ G $, then if exist?

Comment: @Salvattore: Not sure what you are asking. I have mentioned a necessary condition. If $G$ is a simple group like, say, $A_5$ which has $60$ elements, there is no homomorphism with image size $30$ even though $30$ divides $60$. The only possible image sizes are $1$ and $60$ because $A_5$ has no nontrivial proper normal subgroups which might serve as kernels for $\phi$.